# Get UniqueID from splist how to , i only get the ID , but i want UNIQUE?

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            int index = 0;

            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
            if (row != null)
            {
                index = row.RowIndex;
            }

            Label labelID = (Label)GridViewNewsFeed.Rows[index].FindControl("HiddenFieldID");
            HiddenField1.Value = labelID.Text;





            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

            query.Lists = "<Lists>" +
                          "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                          "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("CompanyNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                          "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("ManagementNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                          "</Lists>";
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + labelID.Text + "</Value></Eq></Where>"; 



            query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Attachments\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Authors\" />" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Link\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Contents\" />" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Categories\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Date1\" Nullable=\"TRUE\"/>" + "<FieldRef Name=\"UniqueId\"/>";


           query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

           query.RowLimit = 5;

           DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);

            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

            DetailsView1.DataSource = dv;
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Label1.Text = x.Message;
        }
    }
```

i cant get the unique id how should i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is not UniqueId property on the SPList, but rather on the SPListItem, so you should use the ID as it is already unique, being a GUID (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587801(v=office.11).aspx)